# Big Cartel - Slideshow Questions

Tags: jquery, html, css, bigcartel

First a link to my site: http://johnathonpowers.bigcartel.com/

I have been playing around with the slideshow and was able to migrate it from the home page to a custom page. Initially had it on a test page, but thought it was cause a footer issue (due to too many items in footer perhaps) and it is temporarily on my About page.

So I moved this:

```
{% if theme.image_sets.slideshow.size > 0 %}
<div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
  {% for image in theme.image_sets.slideshow %}
  <li><img src="{{ image.url }}"></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

...from my home page to my about my page. When doing so the arrows no longer appear visible. I tried some code that is supposed to make them always appear, but still no luck.

This is what I added at the end of the CSS page. Did not help though.

```
.flex-direction-nav li a { 
 opacity: 1; 
 }
```

Also is it possible for me to have this slideshow in my product pages? Or to have multiple slideshows throughout the site?

I know I am probably getting fairly advanced, but my ultimate goal was to have a slideshow for product images replacing the "list" of product images. When adding product images it throws them in one column to the right of the product page and I think a slideshow of sorts might look nicer.

Here is a page for an example...(see how the images are one after another). 
I cannot post more than two links. Please view the "Sleepless Bricks" not the framed page.

I actually was trying to figure out a way to have the image, then tiny images underneath (like at clothing websites or something) that you click on to change the image. A zoom function is also something I was reading about adding through something called jquery?

Ultimately I would like to do this on my product pages (a large image with thumbnails underneath):
http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom

Sorry this post went all over the place. Thanks for any help figuring out a solution to my product images and slideshows.

Comment: No one is going to help you if you don't post any code

Comment: Yuval; 
Thanks for the suggestion. Updated my post to reflect and hopefully the two part question makes more sense now (one regarding slideshows and the other replacing product images).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force those arrows to appear on a custom page by adding the following to Customize Design > Advanced > CSS, at the bottom:

```
#page_body .flex-direction-nav a {
  display: block;
}
```

And the Luna theme uses Flexslider for slideshow code, you shouldn't have any problems adding that to a product page or other built-in pages in your store. Flexslider supports multiple slideshows as well, so you may want to check out their documentation at https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider for information on how to do that.

As for the image zoom script, I've answered a question on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22665701/2445073

Comment: Sorry I never responded Nick. Thanks for taking the time to help and answer this question.