# Big Cartel - JQuery Upload/Location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bigcartel

Here is a link to my site, http://johnathonpowers.bigcartel.com

Trying to play around with images on my product pages...well actually created a [test page](http://johnathonpowers.bigcartel.com/test).

Unable to figure out a few things:

1. Where does one host a jquery file?
2. Do I need to have the jquery src for both jquery.min.js (many use the one hosted by google, if I am understanding any of this correctly) and jquery.elevatezoom.js?
3. If I end up not liking the zoom is this still an appropriate way to have a large image with small thumbnails beneath (perhaps I will explore how to click on the big image to open a full-screen version).
4. Should all my pictures be the same size? Right now I have square format photos and rectangle...it might end up looking horrible.
5. Do I put any code into CSS or just the layout and the specific page I want the images to take place?
6. Will these images replace the ones I upload through bigcartel's system?
7. There is already a jquery entry in the layout...do I just add to the end of this same section the additional src?

This is what I added to layout: 
`<script src="http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=24823496361920795072" type="text/javascript"></script>`

This is my test page:
`<img id="zoom_01" src="http://i.imgur.com/1L86Fcms.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://i.imgur.com/1L86Fcm.jpg"/>
$("#img_01").elevateZoom();
<head><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script></head>
<img id="product_zoom" src="http://i.imgur.com/1L86Fcms.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://i.imgur.com/1L86Fcm.jpg" class="fade_in">`

Thanks again for all the help and honestly probably biting off more than I can chew. I just wanted to play around with it and see if it would work/was something I liked, but seems like I have gone down a rabbit hole into a whole other world, way above my rudimentary html skillset.

Here is where I first saw the jquery stuff:
[Can I integrate an Internal zoom on my products in my big cartel store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640408/can-i-integrate-an-internal-zoom-on-my-products-in-my-big-cartel-store/22665701#22665701)

Answer (score 1):

The best place to host your javascript files is on a server that you have control over  -but if you don't have any webspace, you can easily host files with a service like Dropbox or Google Drive.

The Luna theme you're using already loads jQuery in the `<head>` portion of your Layout, so you don't need to include that script again (and you'll get errors in your browser's javascript console if you try).

Since you're using a separate image zooming library that has a bunch of custom CSS, you'll probably want to have your CSS file hosted on a separate server as well. It's a good idea to put any files you're including in the Layout section, following the same format as the existing theme files.

It looks like the javascript file you're hosting on tinyupload.com is just bringing up a download page instead of actually loading the javascript content into the page, so you'll definitely need to change how that's loaded. Otherwise the HTML code you're using looks like it should work.

Comment: Nick I appreciate all the help, but I probably will give up on this one haha. First I owe you a lunch, seriously. I need to figure out the message system here and send you a message. 
Anyway, here is what I have right now. It is a mess, I know, I was just playing around with everything for an hour or more, to see the changes and what did what. 

http://i.imgur.com/biJRGHa.png and http://i.imgur.com/eZx15ye.png and http://i.imgur.com/WeLC1zs.png

That is three images of each of the pages. Not sure where my javascript should be going. Also if my link is correct through google drive...

Comment: ...as I am linking to the folder of files. You mention uploading a link for my CSS? Should I copy/paste the CSS at the bottom (relative to this zoom script) into notepad or similar and upload that? I didn't see any specific CSS files/stuff in the download stuff from the elevate website. Honestly for the time being I am more interested in sorting out the gallery of photos, then tackling the zoom (if I can even handle this task). It is getting fairly advanced and might be better for me to eventually hire someone, although I still wouldn't learn for future products added in doing it myself.