# Integrate an Internal zoom on my products in my big cartel store

Tags: jquery, zooming, bigcartel

I've followed another answer from a qustion with this problem [Can I integrate an Internal zoom on my products in my big cartel store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640408/can-i-integrate-an-internal-zoom-on-my-products-in-my-big-cartel-store)

I have a Bigcartel webshop with the Luna Theme. I will like to integrate an internal zoom on my products images. But i can't get it to work.

I've added the jquery.elevatezoom.js file like this:

`<script src='http://pawsfabrik.dk/jquery.elevatezoom.js'></script>`
In the Layout file.

I've changed the code for the image in the Product page file to this:

`<img id="zoom_01" src="{{ image | product_image_url: "fullsize" }}" data-zoom-image="{{ image | product_image_url: "fullsize" }}" class="fade_in" alt="Image of {{ product.name | escape }}">`

And finally i've added the script code to activate, also in the Product file:

`<script>
    $('#zoom_01').elevateZoom({
    zoomType: "inner",
cursor: "crosshair",
zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
zoomWindowFadeOut: 750
   }); 
</script>`

But it still doesn't work. Anybody who can tell me what i've done wrong? I'm getting really frustrated about it:-(

Thanx,
Paw

Comment: All of the code you've included looks correct as far as I can tell. Can you provide more details on what isn't working exactly? Are you seeing any errors in your browser's console? Or can you post a link to your store?

Comment: Sure. It is the mouse rollover zoom effect that doesn't work. It doesn't have any effect on the image. Please take a look at the site here: http://tillieburden.bigcartel.com/product/forest

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Magic Zoom. Here is a Big Cartel website using it:

http://beetea.bigcartel.com/product/test-product-2

That site zooms the image to the side. Instead, you can use the [internal zoom](http://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoom/integration/#internal) option to make the zoom happen within your main image.

Add Magic Zoom to the Layout file e.g.

```
<script src='http://pawsfabrik.dk/magiczoom.js'></script>
```

Then add the product image code like so:

```
<a href="{{ image | product_image_url: "fullsize" }}" class="MagicZoom" rel="zoom-position: inner"><img src="{{ image | product_image_url: "fullsize" }}" alt="Image of {{ product.name | escape }}"/></a>
```

Comment: Wow i think its working, but i have to by a license because its a webshop. 29 GBP is a little too expensive i guess. Do you know one that is free or maby cheaper?

Comment: Ah, I finally got it to work now. The problem was that the ´jquery.elevatezoom.js´ has to be uploadet to the same server at the site. It works perfectly now. Thank you for trying to help me:-)